# Extracting a case class with an upper bound

Tags: json, scala, lift

I want to extract a case class from a JSON String, and reuse the code for every class. 
Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089409/extracting-lift-json-into-a-case-class-with-an-upper-bound) would have been perfect. But this means that I have to write for every class I want to extract.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
abstract class SocialMonitorParser[C <: SocialMonitorData] extends Serializable {

  def toJSON(socialMonitorData: C): String = {
    Requirements.notNull(socialMonitorData, "This field cannot be NULL!")
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    write(socialMonitorData)
  }

  def fromJSON(json: String): Option[C] = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.
    val jsonObj = liftweb.json.parse(json)

    try {
      val socialData = jsonObj.extract[C]
      Some(socialData)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        Logger.get(this.getClass.getName).warn("Unable to parse the following JSON:\n" + json + "\nException:\n" + e.toString())
        None
      }
    }
  }

}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error:(43, 39) No Manifest available for C.
val socialData = jsonObj.extract[C]
Error:(43, 39) not enough arguments for method extract: (implicit formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats, implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[C])C.
Unspecified value parameter mf.
val socialData = jsonObj.extract[C]
```

I was hoping I could do something like this, and maybe there is a way. But I can't wrap my head around this.

I will try to extend the question with some other information. Supposing I have Twitter and Facebook data, in case class like these:

```
case class FacebookData(raw_data: String, id: String, social: String) extends SocialMonitorData
case class TwitterData(...) extends SocialMonitorData{ ...}
```

I wish I could reuse the `fromJSON` and `toJSON` just once passing the Upper Bound type

```
class TwitterParser extends SocialMonitorParser[TwitterData] {
```

override FromJSON}
    class FacebookParser extends SocialMonitorParser[FacebookData]

Much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want `SocialMonitorParser` to be `abstract` or `Serializable` or how are you going to use it but if you look closer at the error you may see that the compilers wants a `Manifest` for `C`. [`Manifest`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) is a Scala way to preserve type information through the type erasure enforced onto generics by JVM. And if you fix that, then the code like this compiles:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization._

trait SocialMonitorData

case class FacebookData(raw_data: String, id: String, social: String) extends SocialMonitorData


class SocialMonitorParser[C <: SocialMonitorData : Manifest] extends Serializable {

  def toJSON(socialMonitorData: C): String = {
    // Requirements.notNull(socialMonitorData, "This field cannot be NULL!")
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    write(socialMonitorData)
  }

  def fromJSON(json: String): Option[C] = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.
    val jsonObj = parse(json)

    try {
      val socialData = jsonObj.extract[C]
      Some(socialData)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        // Logger.get(this.getClass.getName).warn("Unable to parse the following JSON:\n" + json + "\nException:\n" + e.toString())
        None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and you can use it as

```
def test(): Unit = {
  val parser = new SocialMonitorParser[FacebookData]

  val src = FacebookData("fb_raw_data", "fb_id", "fb_social")
  println(s"src = $src")

  val json = parser.toJSON(src)
  println(s"json = $json")

  val back = parser.fromJSON(json)
  println(s"back = $back")
}
```

to get the output exactly as one would expect.

Comment: Thank you.. at the end I made it work with the `implicit m: Manifest[SocialData]` but actually your solution is better.